# How do I add username of logged in user to model field in django

Tags: python, django

How to add username of currently logged in user to field in my model? For example, I need to store info about user like name, email and so on in model, other than default Django user model, but I still use default one to store credentials. I want to establish relationship between those, so I created `username` field in my model. How do I fill it with current user's username upon saving the corresponding form?
My model

```
class ApplicantProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    dob = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    description = models.TextField()
    username = <something>
```

What do I change `<something>` with?

My form

```
class ApplicantProfileEdit(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ApplicantProfile
    fields = [
        'name',
        'dob',
        'email',
        'description',
    ]
```

My view

```
def ApplEditView(request):
    form = ApplicantProfileEdit(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       form = ApplicantProfileEdit()
    context = {
       'form':form
    }
    return render(request, "applProfileEdit.html", context)
```

P.S. I tried to import models straight to my `views.py`, and assign `request.user.username` to `username` field of the model in my view, but it didn't work, just left that field empty. I had `username` as `CharField` when I tried this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a good idea to save the username itself, or at least not without a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. If later a user changes their name, then the username now points to a non-existing user, if later another user for example changes their username to thatusername, then your `ApplicantProfile` will point to the wrong user.

Normally one uses a [**`ForeignKey`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), or in case each `ApplicantProfile` points to a different user, a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class ApplicantProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    dob = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    description = models.TextField()
    # maybe a OneToOneField
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def appl_edit_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApplicantProfileEdit(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    else:
        form = ApplicantProfileEdit()
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'applProfileEdit.html', context)
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now i cannot apply my migrations. Console output is `The row in table 'workfair_applicantprofile' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: workfair_applicantprofile.username_id contains a value '' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.id.`  Can it be caused by the fact, that I've already created an entry to test out my code?

Comment: Yes, it was the case. I deleted existing database entry and it worked just fine.